# how to sign xml with xades signature

Tags: java, certificate, signature, xades4j, xades

---

i need to sign xml file with standard xsades signature using java.
I know that i need to add extra field when generating signature:

A certificate can be considered a seal
That in the field description of the entity must have the organization identifier box (OID.2.5.4.97) in the format:
(VATPL).*?(?\d{10})

This is xml file that i need to sign:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:InitSessionSignedRequest
    xmlns="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/online/types/2021/10/01/0001"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/types/2021/10/01/0001"
    xmlns:ns3="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/online/auth/request/2021/10/01/0001">
    <ns3:Context>
        <Challenge>20211001-CR-FFFFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFFFF-FF</Challenge>
        <Identifier xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SubjectIdentifierByCompanyType">
            <ns2:Identifier>1111111111</ns2:Identifier>
        </Identifier>
        <DocumentType>
            <ns2:Service>KSeF</ns2:Service>
            <ns2:FormCode>
                <ns2:SystemCode>FA (1)</ns2:SystemCode>
                <ns2:SchemaVersion>1-0E</ns2:SchemaVersion>
                <ns2:TargetNamespace>http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2021/11/29/11089/</ns2:TargetNamespace>
                <ns2:Value>FA</ns2:Value>
            </ns2:FormCode>
        </DocumentType>
        <Type>SerialNumber</Type>
    </ns3:Context>
</ns3:InitSessionSignedRequest>
```

And as result (already signed file) i need to get something like this:
[image]

I have used xades4j library in java to generate signature, but api that i need to connect says that this signature is incorrect.(https://gist.github.com/JohnnyJosep/29cd545db3d0b7abd23279b56d4db194)
Signature that i make looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ns3:InitSessionSignedRequest xmlns:ns3="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/online/auth/request/2021/10/01/0001" xmlns="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/online/types/2021/10/01/0001" xmlns:ns2="http://ksef.mf.gov.pl/schema/gtw/svc/types/2021/10/01/0001" Id="Body">
    <ns3:Context>
        <Challenge>20211001-CR-FFFFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFFFF-FF</Challenge>
        <Identifier xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SubjectIdentifierByCompanyType">
            <ns2:Identifier>1111111111</ns2:Identifier>
        </Identifier>
        <DocumentType>
            <ns2:Service>KSeF</ns2:Service>
            <ns2:FormCode>
                <ns2:SystemCode>FA (1)</ns2:SystemCode>
                <ns2:SchemaVersion>1-0E</ns2:SchemaVersion>
                <ns2:TargetNamespace>http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2021/11/29/11089/</ns2:TargetNamespace>
                <ns2:Value>FA</ns2:Value>
            </ns2:FormCode>
        </DocumentType>
        <Type>SerialNumber</Type>
    </ns3:Context>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039-ref0" URI="#Body">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>ThmCZYvEcORiileK+Nx4NV6k2saOLI7X6y9X9eull08=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039-signedprops">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>2BB1wYgxhtNJrEXQoDVe4FCutxbkx76per3PsVQmvrQ=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039-sigvalue">
HNEFFTjWuo5FtZtYNTrLFPDKBsfHcQ8UGkeUGTUYd9g8b7XZkEMeuuJbPeAaxA1bjN95VwJbUcX4
RdgAq6s+d9VXyVZUA95ZYbDfZPS/9HeQ9QgLLjuFn5GeOBsraRoVlFTyob+fiH70/zR5E8sUA/bU
jzVidvK+mkL1a7HiM9ZNxL2u3ISFoyMMtgT6IMK19lTcW8YM5AZXra0RqB5yMfh4AkC2opE4L6wy
/wkmZSqlg0uxp6I4BZNU+HiJp6PjCB0/0Tn8BmYJMay7Nw+iKSbqH/3fgAaaHKt58YVz1/TTL0Bq
MqiYGywLnNHH+o59Q7lMMFNSiFoJTwG9LbCeog==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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=
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-b63f0f76-3730-4f41-9f98-bc04dec29039-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2022-01-17T01:21:39.053+01:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>s+3AzHds0CJl04O2yScvME5SNJS4iy2gDJbNJnWr/bI=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#161b6b61637a6d6172656b2e6a6163656b313040676d61696c2e636f6d,CN=Jacek,OU=BTC,O=BTC,L=Poznan,ST=Wielkopolska,C=PL</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>583660489997475235588184561339395748006314855657</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
</ds:Signature></ns3:InitSessionSignedRequest>
```

Response from api says "Incorrect signature"
Link to swagger: https://ksef-test.mf.gov.pl/swagger/index.html?api=KSeF-online.yaml#/Interfejsy%20interaktywne%20-%20sesja/initSessionSigned

Is my signature correct or i need to use e.g another library?
I see small differencec beetwen what i have and what i need to get, but i don't know if that is a problem.

Comment: Do you have any additional error details from the validation? It can be invalid for so many reasons.. Are you using the code in the linked Gist to produce the signature? The DocumentBuilderFactory should be set to be namespace aware.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find mistake in your code but but we managed to integrate with xsef api using cefdigital library, usage is described here: https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_the_xml_signature_xades

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a code sample how you create the signature?

It is difficult to say without it, as probably the signature itself also has been corrupted (formatted) when copying it directly to the code block.

In DSS you also need to ensure you use the same signatureParameters configuration (including `bLevel.signingTime`), to create a valid signature.

Best regards,
Aleksandr.